# Slow download speed from build.phonegap.com

Tags: android, cordova, apk, phonegap

I dont know why my speed is slow when i download compiled .apk from Phonegap Build, my internet speed is fine and i have 7.47mbp/s

But when i try to download from phonegap build, my download speed is 20kbp/s 
how can i fix it ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is wrong place to ask why some website on the internet works slow. You don't have any problems with android, phonegap or cordova in your question.

Comment: i have problem with official cordova/phonegap build website, this site is not "some website", this site need for compile and download created android applications.

Comment: This restriction could be imposed by the server to specific or all regions. This is a very broad question and you should properly investigate it by using VPN or other services. Also You should ask this on SuperUser.